# Spring Batch for two different downloads

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I need to implement Spring Batch for two different download types. Based on the user type I would like to serve them two various download results. I read it from the same place, process it in the same way, but file content will be different.

I decided to go with two different jobs for it.

Questions:
Is it possible to reuse Reader and Processor Beans for these two jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible and also very simple, you just have to declare both reader and processor beans out the jobs definition and call them by their id in your step.

Here's an example with the reader.

Bean definition :

```
<bean id="myReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="${resourceLocation} />
</bean>
```

Reference the bean in your step :

```
<batch:step>
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="myReader" />
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

You can call this reader multiple times.